# Intranet Chat Server - for closed office network

Tags: instant-messaging, intranet

We have a closed office network, and our company has grown to the point where we could use some chat capabilities in house. Preferably, the server should be able to support protocols that could enable people to connect to it from available desktop clients (Pidgin, Empathy) on windows and linux. It could be open source or propriety, as long as it works well and not too difficult to set up. Being able to send files and chat-room capabilities will be a huge plus. Anyone familiar with something like that? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use openfire jabber server. 
Perfect for internal office use (a lot of plugins, can be integrated with AD, crossplatform, supports groupping of users, etc).
We have 300 clients (10 of them on linux using Psi).
http://www.igniterealtime.org/

Answer (score 1):

I have chosen ejabberd, it's standard, easy to setup on any linux, supports LDAP out of the box and provides all the xmpp features you might need (file transfert, conferences, and so on...)

I have some notes here in case you want to setup a test bed: http://wiki.linuxwall.info/doku.php/en:ressources:articles:ejabberd

Answer (score 1):

Beside the obvious jabber route, if you happen to run Microsoft Exchange, Office Communications Server is a tightly integrated solution with Mac, Windows, web and mobile web clients (and [a workable](http://kungfucodemonkey.blogspot.com/2009/06/ms-office-communicator-on-linux.html) Linux/Pidgin solution in the [SIPE](http://sipe.sourceforge.net/) project, not tested it though).